# How to access virtual host made on XAMPP via smartphone?

Tags: mobile, virtualhost

I have a website running on my localhost, and it is set up as virtual host.
The problem is, it is no problem at all and works really okay on web browser on my computer, but is not accessible from my mobile phone.

Because virtual host is setup on my local, I know it works well when I access via web browsers on my computer.
But then how to access to this on mobile phone?

What I know is that in order to make accessible by mobile phone, it has absolute address by ip address, i.e, `http://192.168.0.1/mysite`

But due to complicated config made, the site is not working when to access as

```
http://192.168.0.1/mysite
```

but only works when

```
http://dev.mysite.com
```

(`http://dev.mysite.com`  is the virtual host made on my local which is pointing to `http://192.168.0.1/mysite`)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your mobile phone connected to your local network?

Comment: Make sure the web server (Apache in your case) is listening on 0.0.0.0 and not 127.0.0.1.
http://serverfault.com/questions/226231/how-to-make-apache-listen-on-a-particular-ip

Comment: @Pekka웃 yup, it s actually iphone

Comment: @Adir Will you give me detailed guide as an answer?